# Accessing Chef::Config during chefspec run / variables outside action

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

Say I have this spec file:

```rb
require 'chefspec'

describe 'dummy::dummy' do
  step_into 'dummy_dummy'
  platform 'ubuntu'

  context 'creates directory' do
    recipe do
      dummy_dummy 'foo'
    end

    it { is_expected.to create_directory(Chef::Config['file_cache_path']) }
  end
end
```

and this resource:

```rb
unified_mode true

action :create do
  work_dir = Chef::Config['file_cache_path']

  directory work_dir
end
```

Everything works as expected. But if I move the variable assignment outside of the action block like this...

```rb
unified_mode true

work_dir = Chef::Config['file_cache_path']

action :create do
  directory work_dir
end
```

the test fails, because apparently the `file_cache_path` has changed!?

```
  1) dummy::dummy creates directory is expected to create directory "/tmp/d20220910-2861475-7k8xwa"
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to create_directory(Chef::Config['file_cache_path']) }
     
       expected "directory[/tmp/d20220910-2861475-7k8xwa]" with action :create to be in Chef run. Other directory resources:
     
         directory[/tmp/d20220910-2861475-8elovz]
```

Why? Am I not supposed to define variables outside of action blocks? Is accessing Chef::Config from chefspec not supported?

Answer (score 0):

We need to use [action_class](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resource_glossary/#action_class) method of custom resource to make Ruby methods available to all actions in a custom resource. So we can write a method in your custom resource (within `action_class`) to return the required value.

Example:

```rb
unified_mode true

action_class do
  def work_dir
    Chef::Config['file_cache_path']
  end
end

action :create do
  directory work_dir
end
```

Here we have a simple method `work_dir` that returns the value of `Chef::Config['file_cache_path']` when called.